# Мысли персонажа

Tags: прямая-речь, диалог

В диалоге персонажей один из героев рассказывает историю, в которой идет описание другого диалога. Можно ли не заключать в кавычки реплики из его повествования, так как их много и в кавычках диалог смотрится уже не так легко? Как можно оформить текст в таком случае?

Приведу пример (текст придумала, чтобы показать конструкцию):

— Тогда расскажи нам эту историю.

— Это произошло давно. Обстоятельства были необычными и интересными. Напротив меня сидел весьма странный мужчина. Неожиданно он спросил: "Вы хотите рассказать мне что-то?.."

Я подумал и ответил:

"Если вы умеете хранить тайны..."

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Артем. Вы внесли изменения в мой вопрос - я знаю разницу между коротким и длинным тире, но разве я прохожу здесь корректорскую правку перед публикацией книги?..) И разве не будет понятен смысл текста для читателей, если будет не длинное, а короткое тире?)

Comment: Да нет, всё будет понятно и так, но не хватало ещё пробела. Вам жалко, что ли?

Comment: Просто удивилась, ведь это же мой вопрос. Но, если такие правила, то можете еще что-нибудь исправить)

Comment: Странно, что пробела не хватало. Пробелы я люблю. И ставлю

Comment: Пробелов после тире не хватало. Кстати, у вас "но если" не разделяется запятой в комментарии, ведь следует "то".

Comment: Я о них и говорю, после тире. Запятую после "но" поставила для вас:)

Comment: Видимо, был какой-то глобальный сбой системы. И пробелы исчезли

Comment: Пробелы? А у меня они все время удлиняются сами собой, но я сначала набираю текст отдельно, потом копирую его сюда. Ну а потом приходится исправлять, здесь с этим строго. Например: у вас здесь неправильно оформлены 20 пробелов, как можно так писать?! Действительно, как? Не буду же я нажимать клавишу два раза... :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, как мне кажется, два возможных варианта. Короткие разговоры оформляем внутри основного диалога, а развернутые диалоги выносятся ОТДЕЛЬНО и как-то обозначаются при этом.  Я видела оформление с многоточием в современной литературе - там в рассказ героини об одном дне своей жизни на протяжении всей книги прерывают воспоминания о прошлом, и такой переход обозначался только многоточием.

1. Образцы оформления вставленной речи **небольшого объема** можно посмотреть **у Лермонтова** (глава «Бэла»). Там идет **основной диалог**, а вставленные разговоры персонажей заключаются **в кавычки**.

— Как же это случилось?

— Вот (он набил трубку, затянулся и начал рассказывать), вот изволите видеть, я тогда стоял в крепости за Тереком с ротой — этому скоро пять лет. Раз, осенью, пришел транспорт с провиантом; в транспорте был офицер, молодой человек лет двадцати пяти. Он явился ко мне в полной форме и объявил, что ему велено остаться у меня в крепости. Он был такой тоненький, беленький, на нем мундир был такой новенький, что я тотчас догадался, что он на Кавказе у нас недавно. «*Вы, верно, — спросил я его, — переведены сюда из России?*» — «*Точно так, господин штабс-капитан*», — отвечал он. Я взял его за руку и сказал: «*Очень рад, очень рад. Вам будет немножко скучно… ну, да мы с вами будем жить по-приятельски. Да, пожалуйста, зовите меня просто Максим Максимыч, и, пожалуйста, — к чему эта полная форма? приходите ко мне всегда в фуражке»*. Ему отвели квартиру, и он поселился в крепости.

[https://kartaslov.ru/русская-классика/Лермонтов_М_Ю/Герой_нашего_времени/2](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C_%D0%AE/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/2)

2. Если вставка имеет **значительный объем**, то можно оформить так.

— Тогда расскажи нам эту историю.

...Это произошло давно. Обстоятельства были необычными и интересными. Напротив меня сидел весьма странный мужчина. Неожиданно он спросил:

— Вы хотите рассказать мне что-то?

Я подумал и ответил:

— Если вы умеете хранить тайны...

Comment: Спасибо, я хотела, наверное, отметить, что тексты с прямой речью читаются несколько сложно. Слова персонажей не разделены на абзацы и сливаются в единое целое. В особенности для детской аудитории это может сложно восприниматься. Поэтому хотела найти другие варианты оформления, чтобы облегчить восприятие диалогов.

Comment: Спасибо! О возможности оформить с многоточием вначале также написал grizzly. Первоначально я так и оформила...

Comment: Спасибо за ваше доверие. Да,  действительно, многоточие – это знак с разнообразными функциями. К примеру, здесь нужна какая-то отбивка текста, но трудно представить, что еще, кроме многоточия,  можно использовать для этого в художественной литературе.

Answer (score 3):

В диалоге длинный рассказ плохо смотрится в любом случае, поэтому лучше вынести его из диалога.

---

— Тогда расскажи нам эту историю.
— Хорошо, — согласился А. и начал свой рассказ.

Это произошло давно. Обстоятельства были необычными и интересными. Напротив меня сидел весьма странный мужчина. Неожиданно он спросил:
— Вы хотите рассказать мне что-то?..
Я подумал и ответил:
— Если вы умеете хранить тайны...
...

---

[Ссылка с примером](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=IfHTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%22&dq=%22%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUpOD4_djwAhVUr4sKHeaGCO8Q6AEwB3oECAcQAg), и [ещё одна](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=dlHlAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%22&dq=%22%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR0ceJ-tjwAhVrpYsKHanCB1k4KBDoATACegQIBhAC).

Comment: А каким образом это сделать? В вашем примере стоит пробел, далее идет повествование без кавычек?

Comment: Какая-то отбивка обычно есть. Это зависит от авторского стиля и от размера вставки. Вертикальные пробелы обычно не приветствуются, но можно поставить какой-то заголовок, звёздочки или номер подглавы (если рассказ длинный). В минимальном варианте хотя бы многоточие (ссылки на примеры с таким оформлением я добавил в ответ).

Comment: А если рассказ персонажа внутри диалога заключить в кавычки? То есть кавычки будут всего в двух местах.

Comment: @Marusya Думаю, такого оформления я ни разу не встречал. Выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: Не увидела сразу ваши ссылки с примерами на многоточие в начале рассказа. Интуитивно я так и ставила их сама)